# CodeBlocks C++ Exception

Tags: c++, exception, codeblocks

I'm having problem with this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

long long addV(int i) {
    return pow(10,i);
}

int len;

void recurse(int n,long long &ways,int values[],int current=0,int p=0) {
    if(p>len) return;
    if(current>n) return;
    if(current ==n) {
        ways++;
        return;
    }
    int cv = n-current;
    cv/=values[p];

    for(int i=0;i<=cv;i++) {
    recurse(n,ways,values,current+values[p]*i,p+1);
    }
}


int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    long long ways=0;
    int values[] ={1,2,3};
    len = sizeof(values)/sizeof(int);
    recurse(n,ways,values);
    cout<<ways;
}
```

The exception comes from (cv/=values[p];) line. Of course the shitty CodeBlocks never shows what the exception is.
I'm sure its something easy to fix.

Comment: can you show me example of try/catch use ? I havent used it in C++

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_exceptions_handling.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
if(p>len)return;
```

Indeed you've already accessed over boundary when `p == len`. You need to return once `p >= len`.

Answer (score 1):

Because among your ending condition for the recursion is `p > len` which means that `p` will be in the range from zero to three (inclusive). And as you know, an array of three entries have the indexes range from zero to two.